# Getting errors when searching through a vector?

Tags: c++

Header

```
#ifndef BBOARD_H
#define BBOARD_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class User{
};
class Message{
};
class BBoard{
private:
    string title;
    vector<User> user_list;
    User current_user;
    vector<Message> message_list;
public:
    BBoard();
    BBoard(const string &ttl);
    void setup(const string &input_file);
    void login();
    void run();
private:
    bool user_exists(const string &name, const string &pass) const;
};

#endif
```

.cpp file

```
#include "BBoard.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

User user_l;
BBoard::BBoard(){
    title = "Hello World";
    vector<User> user_list;
    User current_user;
    vector<Message> message_list;
}

BBoard::BBoard(const string &ttl){
    title = ttl;
}

void BBoard::setup(const string &input_file){
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("users1.txt");
    while(!fin.eof()){
        user_list.push_back(user_l);
    }
}

bool BBoard::user_exists(const string &name, const string &pass) const{
    vector<User>::iterator i = find(user_list.begin(), user_list.end(), name);
}

void BBoard::login(){
    string sn, pw;
    cout << "Welcome to " << title << endl;
    bookmark:
    cout << "Enter our username ('Q' or 'q' to quit): ";
    getline(cin, sn);
    cout << "Enter your password: ('Q' or 'q' to quit): ";
    getline(cin, pw);

}
```

My user_exists function keeps giving an error about no suitable user defined conversion.  I am trying to use user_exists to check for user name and password and if it exists, it will return true.

Comment: Maybe you should tell us the **exact** error.

Answer (score 2):

Your `user_exists` function is `bool` but returns no value. Here is a suggestion:

```
bool BBoard::user_exists(const string &name, const string &pass) const{
    vector<User>::const_iterator i = find(user_list.begin(), user_list.end(), name);
    return !(i == user_list.end());
}
```

Comment: Additionally, he/she needs to use a const_iterator, as the method is declared const.

Comment: The `if (x) return false; return true;` isn't pleasant. Use `return !x;` instead.

Comment: It is giving me the error see reference to function template instantiation '_InIt std::find<std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>,std::string>(_InIt,_InIt,const _Ty &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _InIt=std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<User>>>,
1>              _Myvec=std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<User>>,
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]